# jQuery Replace part of string

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
​<div id="container">
 <input type="text" name="a1" id="a1">
 <input type="text" name="a2" id="a2">
​</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And I want to replace all instance of the text "a" to "b" for the id and name property for all the element inside the div id="container"

so the new code should be like this:

```
​<div id="container">
 <input type="text" name="b1" id="b1">
 <input type="text" name="b2" id="b2">
​</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I just can't seem to be able to make it work using the javascript replace().

Comment: Show us the code you've tried already. Also, you clearly don't want to replace _all_ `a` with `b` because you'd end up with markup like `<input type="text" nbme="b1" id="b1">`. So what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#container input').each(function(){ // Loop through all inputs
    this.name = this.name.replace('a', 'b');  // Replace name
    this.id = this.id.replace('a', 'b');  // Replace ID
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/G3vCf/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#a1').attr('name', 'b1').attr('id', 'b1');
$('#a2').attr('name', 'b2').attr('id', 'b2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").children("input").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    name = name.replace(/a/g, "b");
    id = id.replace(/a/g, "b");

    $(this).attr("name", name);
    $(this).attr("id", id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
 $(function(){
    var html =$('#container').html().replace(/a/g,'b');
    $('#container').html(html);​
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AJj4E/2/)